# Craft 3 / Craft Commerce Installation - Can't see products

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft3

I recently tried to install Craft Commerce onto Craft 3. I installed the plugin via the plugin store and added in the templates folder which I downloaded straight from https://craftcommerce.com/ and also tried the one from https://github.com/craftcms/commerce

However, when I did so, the pages seemed to work OK, but I can't view any products. I don't think I've got the right templates/shop folder, but I'm also not sure how to get the correct version for Craft3.

This is what my products page currently outputs:

[image]

0/5 of the example products are displayed.

I did try to follow the installation guide on the website, but it seems to only work for Craft2.

Comment: If there is any missing template or outdated method you should see an error **if your environment is configured as `devMode => true`** in your config/general.php file. Once we know whether there is any error or not, we can start debugging the problem...
I am pretty sure those templates have outdated bits that won't work in Craft 3, I had to modify them some times.

Comment: Annoyingly this was a caching issue.. When I changed the templates to the Craft3 version it worked. But thank you for pointing out to pop it back over to dev, thats only when I discovered it didn't look right